# Is it possible to add Sharing button for Snapchat?

Tags: api, social-networking, mobile-website, sharing, snapchat

I am creating a mobile version of website. I have added many of the social sharing buttons (links) on my website like - Facebook, Linked In, Twitter. Specially for mobile I have added button to share on WhatsApp. Now I am thinking to enable similer link for Snapchat. Is it possible to provide a link on my site to post a snap of stories in snapchat ?

I have tried to find out for any API to achive, but doesn't found any thing.

From the snapchat blog link following, I found that there is no API available provided by snapchat.
http://blog.snapchat.com/post/99998266095/third-party-applications-and-the-snapchat-api

Is ther any alternative to achive my purpose ?

Comment: Hello @Niraj Chapla did you find snapchat api or sharing button.Same i have to use on my website to share image.I have tried to find out , but doesn't found any thing.

Comment: I also do not found any api for the same.