# How can I add a Snapchat sharing button to my web site? Is it possible to add Sharing button for Snapchat?

Tags: social-networking, sharing, snapchat

I am developing a website.I have added the many social login or sharing buttons, links like Facebook, tweeter, gplus, pintrest on my PHP, html based web site.

Now I have to add the social sharing button for snapchat, is it possible to provide a link or button on my we bsite to share a snap, image, content of stories in Snapchat?

I have tried to find out for any API or Snapchat link or button to achieve, but doesn't find anything.

I also saw the question doesn't have any answer, reply, comments.

[Is it possible to add Sharing button for Snapchat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217307/is-it-possible-to-add-sharing-button-for-snapchat)

From the Snapchat blog link following, I found that there is no API available provided by Snapchat.

http://blog.snapchat.com/post/99998266095/third-party-applications-and-the-snapchat-api

Is it possible to share contents of Snapchat?

Answer (score 2):

That blog post is more talking about using a 3rd party app intead of the snapchat app, this is something i can never see being allowd but is also not what i think you are after.

I assume you mean that you want to be able to share a screenshot or specific image on snapchat. I have not been able to find a way of doing this, the closest thing was a 3rd party app that enabled link insertion to snapchat (http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/06/you-can-now-embed-links-in-snapchat-screenshots-using-emoji/)

On the other hand, if you want them to connect to you, this can be done with the url https://www.snapchat.com/add/yourUserName

hope this helps